# How to determine that someone is a גוסס?

Tags: death, medicine, kohen-priest, choleh-sick

Is there any article or guidebook that tells how to determine that a sick person has reached the stage of being a גוסס (gosess) to the extent that any kohen present should leave?

A [gosess](http://www.rabbiwilson.com/2011/12/28/end-of-life-issues-guidelines-for-rabbanim/)  is a patient who has reached the terminal stage of his illness where nothing else can be done and whose death is imminent.

Comment: does item three help? http://www.rabbiwilson.com/2011/12/28/end-of-life-issues-guidelines-for-rabbanim/

Comment: @Danno Yes thank you - it is a possible answer.

Comment: how about when the doctor says his death is imminent

Comment: @ray That's fine if the doctor is there and is prepared to be so definite.

Answer (score 1):

In [Beshvilai Harefua #6 - Sivan 5744](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=28407&st=&pgnum=35) there is a piece written by Rabbi Moshe Feinstein Zatzal. He says that Doctors can not recognize when someone is Goses.

> ולענין סימני גסיסה שמעתי שהרופאים אין מכירים בהם

Comment: I asked how to determine that a sick person has reached the stage of being a גוסס and you answer that the doctors cannot tell?

Comment: Correct. My answer is that Rabbi Feinstein says that doctors can not tell. Thus how can anyone tell you?

Comment: Rav Feinstein attributes their inability to tell to their ignorance of (a) the din and of (b) the effects of intervention on a goses. So do you think a Talmid Chochom might be able to tell?

Comment: He does not indicate that he knows. So I doubt anyone knows.